# Are gaze attacks subject to spell resistance?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I haven't been able to find an answer for this, just the description for gaze attack over and over saying to cover/avert your eyes to foil such an attack.

I mean, it's clearly magical in nature, and spell like abilities can be blocked by spell resistance, but I just want to be sure in case there's some rule out there that says otherwise.

Comment: Which creature's gaze attack?

Comment: Just gaze attacks in general

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spell resistance applies to spells and spell-like abilities **only**. Absolutely nothing else is affected by it.

So if a gaze attack is a spell or spell-like ability (and the the spell or spell-like ability indicates “SR: Yes” in its description/statblock), then yes. Otherwise—which would be the overwhelming majority of gaze attacks, as almost all are Supernatural—no.

Comment: Thank you for the speedy answer